# Svelte Sapper Server Route 404 Not Found

Tags: http-status-code-404, svelte, sapper

I am using default Sapper `sveltejs/sapper-template#webpack` to start my project

I have a server route called `auth/login` that only accept `POST` request from the same Sapper client script.

The file structure looks like this:

[image]

And the Server route `auth/login` looks like this:

[image]

But I got a `404 Not Found` error, and it even just run under `npm run dev` only:

[image]

I don't understand what is exactly the problem, can anyone please help?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After researching on this problem.  I found that in server route `auth/login` the code missed `async`.

So this is wrong:

`export function post(req, res, next){}`

This is correct.

`export async function post(req, res, next){}`

And it works after I change it.